# Get running LineageOS kernel configuration from adb shell

Tags: android, linux-kernel, lineageos

I have built LineageOS 18.1 from source and flashed that on an ARM device. On the build host, I can see that `lineage/out/target/product/jfltexx/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/.config` contains

```
KERNEL_IKCONFIG=y
KERNEL_IKCONFIG_PROD=y
```

From sources like [this SO post](https://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system), I conclude that this kernel config will enable runtime read access to the kernel configuration on device, e.g. using `adb shell`.

Where exactly in the LineageOS runtime filesystem is this kernel configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It's in the standard place `/proc/config.gz` and can be grepped using `adb shell zcat /proc/config.gz | grep <YOUR_SEARCH_TERM_HERE>`